# How can I get the value of a variable inside a string in SQL?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql

Let a table 'Example' has columns id, value.

```
| id | value |
|--- | ----- |
|1   | randm |
```

Now I want to write something like this

```
SELECT id, 'x is 'value'' as result
FROM Example
WHERE id = 1;
```

which prints

```
| id | result |
| -- | ------ |
| 1  | x is 'randm' |
```

How can I do this? In python, if we use {} in the middle of a string, we could pass variables, which is similar to what I want in SQL.

Comment: Have you tried to use string concatenation for this, either through  `||` or through `CONCAT`?

Comment: Pick your poison: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-string.html

Comment: @NicoHaase I don't just want to concatenate. I want the value in single quotes inside a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT id, format('x is %L', value) as result
FROM Example
WHERE id = 1;

SELECT id, format('x is %s', quote_literal(value)) as result
FROM Example
WHERE id = 1;

SELECT id, format('x is ''%s''', value) as result
FROM Example
WHERE id = 1;

SELECT id, format($$x is '%s'$$, value) as result
FROM Example
WHERE id = 1;
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING

Answer (score 1):

The [operator `||` will concatenate strings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) in Postgres, so it's just:

```
 SELECT id, 'x is ''' || value || '''' AS result
 FROM Example
 WHERE id = 1;
```

Comment: This is giving x is randm, but I want x is 'randm'.

Comment: @GowthamVurimi I've updated. I'm including an escaped single quote (double single quote) in the string literals.